# How do I return multiple identities in a token with Thinktecture.IdentityServer.45?

Tags: claims-based-identity, sts-securitytokenservice, jwt, thinktecture-ident-model, thinktecture-ident-server

In the [Thinktecture.IdentityModel.45](https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityModel.45) library, I can get a `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Claims.ClaimsIdentityCollection` by executing something like this:

```
 Dim handler = New JsonWebTokenHandler()
 handler.Configuration = config ' set elsewhere
 Dim identities = handler.ValidateToken(handler.ReadToken(token))
```

We have a system where a user gets to login and then choose an organizational context they are part of. Each context should be representative of what is available in the token (one identity per organization with a collection of specific claims). How can I get the [Thinktecture.IdentityServer.45](https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityServer.45) to return a token that contains multiple identities?

Answer (score 2):

WIF is generally not designed for this. And only certain token types support this at all.

Comment: Where would I find information on which token types do support this?